# awk part string compare

Tags: awk, filesystems, compare

I trying to extract some part of string using bash or awk.

I think I can solve this problem using read or awk.

my input_file is like below

```
cat ./input_file

in_size=1
# out_size=2
```

so,

```
out_size=$(awk '{if($2=="out_size=2"){ blabla ; print output}' ./input_file)
```

I don't know how to solve this problem.

And, how can I set multiple field separator FS with empty space and tab.

there are example like

```
FS='[/=]'
```

How can I use 4 FS / = " " "\t" ??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `FS="[ \\t]"` ? what on earth do you really want? I don't get what problem do you want to solve.. :(

Comment: yes I tried awk -F FS="[ =]"  , but it's field separator became " =", not empty space " " and "="

Comment: you should either do `awk -F'[ =]' 'code'` or `awk 'BEGIN{FS="[ =]"}...'`. you cannot do `awk -F FS='...'`

Comment: oh I mistook thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Use a POSIX-style character class `[:blank:]` which includes any horizontal whitespace characters.

```
awk -F '=|[[:blank:]]+' '{
    for (i=1; i<NF; i++) {
        if ($i == "out_size") {
            print $(i+1)
            exit
        }
    }
}' filename
```

Unless you know that it's always the 2nd word:

```
awk -F '=|[[:blank:]]+' '$2 == "out_size" {print $3; exit}' filename
```

Comment: Thank you very much. in the '[[:blank:]]+' what is the meaning of '+'? and how can I use this with BEGIN{FS };?? BEGIN{ FS="[=|[[:blank:]]+]"}; was not work

Comment: You want `BEGIN {FS = "=|[[:blank:]]+"}` (without the surrounding brackets). This tells awk that the field separator is either an equal sign or a sequence of whitespace.